# How do I print sprecific words from a list in a file at random

Tags: python, list, file, printing, notepad

```
def song():
    print("Wellcome The Song Game")
    newfile = open("songs.txt","r")
    sangg_2D = eval(newfile.read())
    newfile.close()
    sang2 = sangg_2D[0:11]
    print("The Song Name Is", sang2)
    sangg3 = input("Name The Song")
    found = False
    for count in range(len(sangg_2D)):
        if sangg3 == sangg_2D[count][0]:
            score = score + 2
            found = True
            #score = score+2
            print("welldone You Got The Answer Correct On Your First Try")
        else:
            if found==False:
                print("Wrong Answer Try Again")
                song()
song()
```

it prints every single word in my file and i only want it to print the song artist and a bit of the name

> The Song Name Is [['j.cole', 'MIDDLE CHILD'], ['Mustard', 'Pure
>   Water'], ['Khalid', 'Talk'], ['Cardi B', 'Please Me'], ['Beyoncé',
>   'Before I Let Go'], ['Nav', 'Prices On My Head'], ['Chris Brown',
>   'Back To Love'], ['French Montana', 'Slide'], ['Justin Beiber', 'I
>   Dont Care'], ['Ari Lennox', 'Whipped Cream']]

Comment: Could you provide some sample content from your songs `txt` file?

Comment: @VasilisG.  [['j.cole' , 'MIDDLE CHILD'],
['Mustard' , 'Pure Water'],
['Khalid' , 'Talk'], 
['Cardi B' , 'Please Me'], 
['Beyoncé' , 'Before I Let Go'], 
['Nav' , 'Prices On My Head'], 
['Chris Brown' , 'Back To Love'], 
['French Montana' , 'Slide'], 
['Justin Beiber' , 'I Dont Care'], 
['Ari Lennox' , 'Whipped Cream']]                                                     
                                                                                                         
This is what the list is like in my file songs.txt

Answer (score 0):

From what I am able to understand based on your question and you source code, you want to take a song name and have the user find the correct artist for that song name. If this is the case, then you can simplify your code a lot:

```
import random

def song():
    score = 0
    print("Wellcome The Song Game")
    newfile = open("songs.txt","r")
    sangg_2D = eval(newfile.read())
    newfile.close()
    randomSong = random.randint(0,len(sangg_2D)-1)
    found = False
    while not found:
        sang2 = sangg_2D[randomSong][1]
        print("The Song Name Is", sang2)
        sangg3 = input("Name The Artist")
        if sangg3 == sangg_2D[randomSong][0]:
            score = score + 2
            found = True
            print("welldone You Got The Answer Correct On Your First Try")
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer Try Again")
song()
```

First, you read the file's content to get all artists and their respective songs. It is better to use `ast.literal_eval` from `ast` module, than `eval` by the way. Then you pick a random song from the list and have the user guess the correct artist. If the user finds the artists, then your program is completed, else it asks for the user again to guess the artist. You also need to fix the part with the `score` at first try, because there is no check that the user found it on the first try.